# Lenovo p53s : thunderbolt 3 port : charging and video output at the same time

Tags: lenovo-laptop, thunderbolt

I have a Lenovo p53s. Documentation [here](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t490_t590_p43s_p53s_ug_v2_en.pdf). Specifically page 4 identifying the usb c ports
[image: ports]

One sees two usb-c ports one being thunderbolt 3.

In the description they list the functionalities of those ports stating they can be used for power and video output. However they identify video output through either VGA or display port.

Currently,I am connecting my laptop to the monitor with a usb c to usb c cable. And it works, I have the monitor displaying the picture and my laptop charging. However there are some disconnects and I can’t perform tests (no other laptops) to identify if it’s a laptop issue, a monitor issue, a cable issue or a misuse issue.

From the manual, it would seem they don’t explicite my foresee my usage : 1 cable for both charging one way and video output the other way. But I understood this is the point of thunderbolt.

The screen I have is this [one](https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/3/328p6aubreb_00/328p6aubreb_00_dfu_fra.pdf?_ga=2.245806852.1814357177.1699639662-260672714.1699639662). The docking station included states it’s able to deliver 65w power through the USB-c. So it’s exactly what the p53s needs.

So the question is : based on the manual and my setup, should this work flawlessly ? And then should I start investing issues with the hardware ? (Cable, monitor, or computer)

Comment: Yes, you can do both over one cable, but not always! For example, some USB-C monitors only supply enough power to charge a mobile device, whereas others are able to power a laptop, assuming they're meant to supply power at all. You may be better off getting a laptop dock that you know can provide enough power and also connect to the monitor. Other stuff like the cable or USB drivers could cause similar issues as well.

Comment: I added some details about the monitor. The power rating matches the needs of the computer.

Comment: The typical use-case involves either a dock, hub, or dongle that also takes an additional, e.g., PD input to supplement the gross output to devices.  Also consider peak demand (i.e., when devices switch on).

Comment: What kind of dongle do you have in mind? Link? :)